# Bootstrap Media Object not loading image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load the bootstrap media object inside a span3 div.
Everything works, apart from the image.  I've checked this link elsewhere and it has no issues.

Any suggestions

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
       <div class="pull-left">
       <h3>Top Devices</h3>
           <div class="media">
              <a class="pull-left" href="#">
              <img class="media-object" data-src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>resource/img/devices/Asus-Nexus-7.png"/>
               </a>

       <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">Media heading</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may find it useful to know what's actually going on there:  the bootstrap documentation pages include this js : [link](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/holder/holder.js). it's purpose is to insert images into the src attribute of the img elements where the data-src attribute contains text like:  "holder.js/L64x64".  Agreed, it might be a bit confusing to see it there in the data-src.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just a regular image you are loading into the span3, is there a reason why you are using **data-src** and not **src** ?

Or if you are also using something like foresight.js, for example, see if [this post helps you](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/32)

Good luck!

Comment: I just followed the guidelines on the bootstrap site. I ended up hacking apart the rendered source and using that which did actually use src and has worked :)

Comment: Good going. Hope you have fun with Bootstrap.

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa HI! I have a similar issue. What is going wrong with me, it's that image is not showing. I have copied code from bootstrap page, but changing src for a  valid image url. This is my fiddle : http://fiddle.jshell.net/oy95hh7w/ What's wrong with that?? Thanks I hope you can help me!

Comment: @GmloMalo , have you triple checked that the path to your image, and its file name are correct? Heres' a another jsfiddle with exactly the same code as yours except i've changed the image src: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/956age7d/

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa yes! First sorry for the fiddle file because it was wrong with src i was using my local storage path. But in my code, i have de image stored in img/64x64/image.png where img folder is on root directory but image is not showing. I have checked path and image file name and is all correct. My local code is:  <img class="media-object" alt="img/64x64/calculadoras_de_deporte.png" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;" src="img/64x64/image-icon.png" data-holder-rendered="true">, and if i use a a web image like the fiddle file, it neither showing

Comment: @GmloMalo , do you have an online page (on your site) that I can see. It will be easier to diagnose.

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa yes! I have uploaded right now so you can see it to diagnose [link](http://3waynutrition.com/calculadoras/calculadoras-deporte.html) Thanks

Comment: Hey @GmloMalo, do you have the problem fixed now? It's looking good to me: http://is.gd/P8XgxZ

Comment: @DavidTaiaroa no not yet. I can't see the image on any of my devices, pc either smartphone and tablet. I can't understand whats the matter

Comment: I have guess that the problem is with some browsers like chrome, edge, and some others. But i dont know why... Any suggestion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90835/discussion-between-david-taiaroa-and-gmlomalo).

Answer (score -1):

Check the source code out, probably it will gives you the answer.

I think you should add an slash:

data-src="/resource/img/devices/Asus-Nexus-7.png

instead of:

data-src="resource/img/devices/Asus-Nexus-7.png

Grretings